# How do I translate this VB.Net to C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have this code in VB.Net:

```
Dim c As Control

For Each c In Me.Controls

    If TypeOf (c) is PictureBox Then
    CType(c, PictureBox).Image = My.Resources.available
    End If

Next
```

What is appropriate code in C#?

Comment: The VB code is bad to begin with. If you use `For Each pb In Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)()` then you don't need an `If` statement or an additional cast. That code translates directly to C# as `foreach (var pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>)()`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney slight typo correction: `foreach (var pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())`. C# would probably drop the `this` too

Comment: @CaiusJard, thanks for the correction. As for using `this`, I'd certainly drop that myself but it is the direct translation of the `Me` used in the original VB so I chose to include it for that reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is

```
((PictureBox)c).Image = ...
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions

You *cast* `c` to PictureBox

Note that you can also do

```
if (c is PictureBox picbox)
{
   picbox.Image = ...
}
```

This way you *test* that c is a PictureBox and (if so) immediately cast and store in that `picbox` variable.